# App Inventor - logic

Tags: android, app-inventor

This very simple code does not behave the way it should and I don't quite understand why.

App Inventor code:

```
When Button1.Click
#1  set Label1.Text to "Wait"
#2  call ProcedureXYZ
#3  set Label1.Text to "Done"
```

Here's the problem. `ProcedureXYZ` takes 5 seconds to complete. So `Label1` should have displayed "Wait", but it does not. Instead, line #1, #2, #3 get executed simultaneously. In other word, it disappears for 5 second, and then "Done" is shown (that's because it immediately override "Wait").

So for 5 seconds, my app appears to be frozen until `ProcedureXYZ` completes its calculations. My question is, **how do I display "Wait" when `ProcedureXYZ` takes 5 seconds to complete?**

I try using clock to fire up the "Wait" message, but that does not work either. The only thing that work is to display an alert message, but I don't want popup message.

Comment: generally saying, you need threads.

Answer (score 0):

Why this in **App Inventor** does not work like that, is explained here:
[The model of event processing in App Inventor](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/m8i32I2m200/Am3VYo3DTIUJ) by Lyn

You will have to use a `Clock` component to do this, see pseudo code below. In the Designer, set a very small `TimerInterval` (for example 10 milliseconds) and set property `TimerEnabled` to false.

`Button1.Click` event

```
set Label1.Text to "Wait"
set Clock.TimerEnabled to true
```

`Clock.Timer` event

```
set Clock.TimerEnabled to false  
call ProcedureXYZ
set Label1.Text to "Done"
```